# How can we reload html page without blinking

Tags: html

Hello I want to reload my html page without blinking. I am using below code but this is not working properly. Blinking takes place.

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>   
     <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png">  
</body>
```

Comment: I assume by blink you mean the dom being redrawn on page reload? You would probably need an elaborate ajax solution to prevent that ...

Comment: remove the `refresh` `http-equiv` ... you're essentially telling the page to refresh every 3 seconds. therefore you probably are feeling that the page is blinking.

Comment: Try firefox instead of google chrome or Microsoft Internet Explorer